# How to calculate the amount of numbers inside a specific range

Tags: r

I'm still having problems calculating numbers.

Trying to find the amount of numbers inside [-0.5 , 0.5] the first line, and the amount of numbers outside the same range in the second line.

I use `abc = rnorm(100, mean=0, sd=1)`. So I have 100 numbers in total, but i only have 35 numbers inside the range, and 35 outside the range, that dosen't add up to 100.

```
length(abc[abc>=-0.5 & abc<=0.5])
[1] 35

length(abc[abc<-0.5 & abc>0.5])
[1] 35
```

Then I tried:

```
length(which(abc>=-0.5 & abc<=0.5))
[1] 40

length(which(abc<-0.5 & abc>0.5))
[1] 26
```

And it still doesn't add up to 100. What's wrong?

Answer (score 10):

You are after:

```
R> set.seed(1)
R> abc = rnorm(100, mean=0, sd=1)
R> length(abc[abc >= -0.5 & abc <= 0.5])
[1] 41
R> length(abc[abc < -0.5 | abc > 0.5])
[1] 59
```

**What went wrong**

Two things:

1. `abc < -0.5 & abc > 0.5` is asking for values less than -0.5 **and** greater than 0.5
2. However, you actually had: `abc[abc<-0.5 & abc>0.5]` This does something a bit different due to scoping. Let's pull it apart:

   ```
   R> abc[abc<-0.5 & abc>0.5]
    [1] 1.5953 0.7383 0.5758 1.5118 1.1249 0.9438 <snip>
   ```

   Now let's look at `abc`

   ```
   R> abc
   [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
   ```

   You've changed the value of `abc`! This is because `<-` is the assignment operator. You have set `abc` equal to `0.5 & abc > 0.5`. To avoid this, use spacing (as in my code).

Comment: Excellent explanation of the two gotchas here

Answer (score 3):

When wanting to find numbers inside and outside a radius like this, it can be helpful to consider the absolute value, and you then only have one comparison to make:

```
length(abc[abs(abc)<=0.5])
[1] 41
length(abc[abs(abc)>0.5])
[1] 59
```

Or you can use `cut` and `table` to do it in one line:

```
table(cut(abs(abc),c(-Inf,0.5,Inf)))

  (-Inf,0.5] (0.5,Inf] 
       41        59
```

Answer (score 2):

As a shortcut, you can also do it this way :

```
set.seed(1)
abc <- rnorm(100, mean=0, sd=1)
sum(abc>=-0.5 & abc<=0.5)
# [1] 41
sum(abc< -0.5 | abc>0.5)
# [1] 59
```

This works because `sum` considers TRUE as 1 and FALSE as 0.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively via `subset`:

```
set.seed(1)
abc <- rnorm(100, mean=0, sd=1)

length(subset(abc, abc >= (-0.5) & abc <= 0.5))
[1] 41
length(subset(abc, abc < (-0.5) | abc > 0.5))
[1] 59
```